# NextJS src directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I started working with NextJS recently. I can't get my head around if the best practice is to keep all of my code (apart from pages folder) in /src folder just like in create-react-app, or can I put my components in the root? I've seen people use both variants. What is the best practice? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is what we've settled on & doesn't need any config to manage your `pages`. We keep everything inside `src`.

[image]